# Rails 4 content entry system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, blogs, ruby-on-rails-4

I am interested in building a Ruby on Rails 4 application that allows users to enter blog like articles. I don't need a full blown blogging architecture - would be smarter to use WordPress or an open source alternative. I do need a subset of features such as the following:

- add tagging
- rich editing to allow user to bold, underline, highlight content
- create seo friendly URLs based on article headline

The reason I'm posting is I'd rather not reinvent the wheel. I'm wondering if there is a Rails gem that is already built that has these similar features already created so I can plug it in and customize it with my existing application. If there is currently nothing out there because of the existence of tools such as WordPress, I'll have to custom bake them into my own application. Is there currently a solution in form of gem or something similar already out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possible options for you:

- [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) is a gem that works for tagging.
- [rich](https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich) is a rich editor gem. You might want to also think about adding markdown support which can be done using [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet).
- Then try something like [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for seo friendly urls.